# Avoiding "time-controlledly" as an adverb

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, adverbs, writing-style, idiom-requests

I'm currently translating a web site for scheduling software from German to English. So there are many things that this program can do "time-controlledly" (if I translate literally). But this sounds very wrong to my ears, can this construction be used as an adverb? If not, how can I avoid it?

Let me give some specific examples of more-or-less literal translations that I would like to rephrase to make them more idiomatic:

- "You can time-controlledly start and stop programs and services."
- "The program offers many built-in commands such as (X, Y, Z) that can be run time-controlledly and automatically".
- "The program will time-controlledly check your dynamic IP address and send you a mail each time it changed."

I have tried to avoid this problem by using nominalized constructions (so that "time-controlled" modifies a noun instead of a verb) and prepositional phrases ("in a time-controlled way"), but all of this looks very non-idiomatic. I'm looking forward to some suggestions on how to deal with this kind of adverb construction in English.

Comment: I think you're looking for "on a schedule" or one of its cousins.

Comment: Can we have the German for one or two of those sentences?

Comment: @DanielHarbour: Some sentences that I am translating right now: "Dieses Kommando fährt den Computer zeitgesteuert herunter."/"Mit diesem Kommando kann eine dynamische IP-Adresse, die vom Internet-Provider zugeteilt wurde, zeitgesteuert ermittelt werden."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for words like scheduled, automatic and periodically. You can use a thesarus to find alternatives to these words, but here are some examples:

- "You can schedule times for programs and services to run" (or "You
  can schedule the times at which programs and services run.")
- "The program offers many built in commands such as (X, Y, Z) that can be
  scheduled to run automatically"
- "The program will periodically check your dynamic IP address and send an email notification each time it changes."

Answer (score 4):

The word you are  looking for might be *periodically*.  Swap it in your sentences, and it seems to make sense.

Comment: That doesn't carry quite the connotation of control that the OP wants, I think. A process can be periodic but uncontrolled.